# Does Cassandra replication degrades Analytics performance in other DC or vice versa?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We have proposed a solution utilizing Cassandra-Spark combo realized through a Workload separation architecture. That is, the Operations DC mainly undergoes heavy write operations while the Analytics DC processes Analytics jobs. I have read [here](https://academy.datastax.com/planet-cassandra/data-replication-in-nosql-databases-explained) that:

"*Once these asynchronous hints are received on the additional clusters, they undergo the normal write procedures and are assimilated into that data center. This way, any analytical jobs that are running can easily and simply access this new data without a time-consuming ETL process.*"

Our concern is as all the data is replicated near real-time from Operations DC to Analytics DC, how can we be sure that the replication process will not impact the Analytical processing happening on the Analytics DC?

Alternatively, will the heavy processing of Analytic jobs impact the replication of data between DCs?

I understand that I may be missing something, but a direction will help. Will also appreciate any related documentation on benchmarking or theoretical analysis to address this concern.

Answer (score 1):

It's really depends on type of data processing you'll have in the Analytics DC. You need to size servers that they could handle the standard write traffic from replication from transactional DC, plus the load from your analytical jobs. But you can have smaller replication factor for Analytical DC, so it will be slight fewer writes to servers in Analytical DC.

DSE Architecture is described in the [corresponding guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/). You need to look through information on data replication, and read/write paths...

I would suggest to perform load testing of your cluster, and measure the load on the servers in Analytical DC, and, for example, 99th percentiles for read & writes on the servers there.

You can emulate the load to transactional DC using the [DSE Gatling plugin](https://github.com/datastax/gatling-dse-plugin), or related projects (search by word gatling in DataStax repository).  Using Gatling it's easier to develop more real-world-like load simulators.

Comment: **Comment Part: 1**
Thank you, Alex. I've gone through the corresponding guide but unable to find the answers. Currently, we are working on the Architecture of an archiving solution. Use of Gatling and other prototyping activities will follow at a later stage. 

I see that Workload separation architecture helps to isolate the reads and writes by deploying two DCs. But the replication of data from Operations DC to Analytics DC will introduce asynchronous writes on the Analytics DC. Hence, Analytics DC will have writes coming from Operations DC along with the Analytical processing inside it.

Comment: **Comment Part: 2**
I am searching how Cassandra-Spark internal architecture handles the conflicts between replication and analytical processing. What were the options in the architecture considered to cope with such issues? Any architecture best practices to avoid such issues?

I've read the online Datastax documentation but I am unable to locate answers to above questions.

Comment: In conflict resolution, the last timestamp wins - that's simple. Although you can manually set timestamp when writing the data. Or you can write a subset of data, overriding only some columns, that may not be present in the "operations" data. But anyway, if you're writing into the same table/keyspace that is replicated between DCs, data is replicated to another... I have seen when people replicate data into Analytics DC, analyze, and write results into another keyspace that isn't replicated into "Operations DC"... But this always depends on the task. You can contact DataStax to get more info.

Comment: I would add here that if you are worried about replication creating too much load on your nodes then it sounds like you are not thinking about other essential operations like repair, tolerance of node failure etc. Your nodes need to have operational headroom and you need to load test, then load test some more.